# Eslint Exported comment not working for me

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am having an issue using the exported comment to prevent the unused variable warning using eslint. The global comment is working correctly elsewhere in my code.

Warning from eslint:

```
"bootstrap" is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

Code:

```
/* exported bootstrap */
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
```

Comment: Information here might help: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/3833

Answer (score 1):

If you have `node` or `commonjs` environments turned on, they create an extra scope, which means that the variables that would've been marked as global in, say, browser environment, are not accessible globally. As such, you can't mark them as `exported`. So if you want to use variable somewhere outside of the current file, you have to use `modules.export = {...}`. That's why `exported` comment doesn't work.